# How to increase slider length in ipywidgets

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Suppose, I have the following code:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive
import ipywidgets as widgets

def f(x):
    return x
interact(f, x=(0,10,1));
```

The resulting interactive slider is nice but pretty small in terms of horizontal length. When the range of x is large, such as 0 - 1000, it becomes exceedingly difficult taking small steps using that slider. How can I increase the length of the slider?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the Layout component.

Try:

```
from ipywidgets import Layout, interact, IntSlider
import ipywidgets as widgets

def f(x):
    return x
interact(f, x=IntSlider(0, 0, 10, 1, layout=Layout(width='500px')));
```

Answer (score 8):

Besides specifying the pixel value, the width percentage may be more general. In this case, the object looks like this: **`layout=widgets.Layout(width='50%')`**

Full widget example:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

int_wdgt = widgets.IntSlider(
    description='Test widget:',
    value=100,
    min=10, max=100_000, step=1000,
    layout=widgets.Layout(width='50%'))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know one could do that. Awesome!